# Using Lucida Math Std

Tags: fonts, xetex, opentype

I'm trying to use Adobe's Lucida font with the corresponding Lucida Math font (as contained in Adobe Font Folio). Using Lucida as the main font works however when I try to use the math font I get the following error:

570: LaTeX Error: Command \dddot already defined

It also warns me that "Lucida Math Std does not contain script 'Math'. 'Latin' script used instead.

I'm using XeLaTeX. Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Lucida Std}
\setmathfont{Lucida Math Std}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
This is a formula
\begin{align*}
    a+b=c
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try to set `\usepackage{amsmath}` before `\usepackage{unicode-math}`.

Comment: Thanks that helps. Now the document compiles however I get a box like this [x] instead of the + symbol.

Comment: I'm not sure that Lucida Math Std is tailored for usage with `unicode-math`.

Comment: Maybe the real question would be: how much effort it is to map Lucida Math Std in order to be compatible with `unicode-math`? ie. basically this https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/blob/master/unicode-math-table.tex

Answer (score 1):

I do not have your versions of Lucida, but my Lucida works. It is the version from tug.org:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Lucida Bright}
\setmathfont{Lucida Bright Math OT}
\begin{document}
This is a formula
\begin{align*}
    a+b=c
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why it's not working with "my version" isn't working. This is the link to Adobe: http://store1.adobe.com/cfusion/store/html/index.cfm?store=OLS-US&event=displayFontPackage&code=1358

Comment: @user2249626 -- it's quite possible that the version distributed by adobe is not set up for use with tex; the version available from tug *is* set up properly.  the [tug lucida page](http://tug.org/store/lucida/) doesn't appear to provide information on the version available from adobe.

Comment: It looks like that you have to define the different math symbols using the `range` option of `unicode-math`. However, the Lucida Math fonts from tug.org are a better choice: http://tug.org/store/lucida/order.html